# Balmer series for ionized lithium

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy, absorption, photon-emission

I am trying to calculate the wavelength for the first spectral line in a Balmer-series for a two times ionized lithium, $\text{Li}^{2+}$.

I know that the atomic number $z$ is 3 for lithium and it is hydrogen-like since it has lost two of its electrons. I also know that the answer to this question is $72,88 \cdot 10^{-9} m$.

I use this formula with Rydbergs constant and my answer is a bit off from the answer. **How can I get closer to the desired value?** Or is there another way to solve this problem?

$$ \frac{1}{\lambda} = R z^2 \left( \frac{1}{n^2_f} - \frac{1}{n^2_i} \right) \\ \frac{1}{\lambda} = 1.0973731 \cdot 10^7 \cdot 3^2 \left( \frac{1}{2^2} - \frac{1}{3^3} \right) \rightarrow \lambda = 72.90 \cdot 10^{-9} m $$

Comment: So being off by 2 in 7288 is bad?

Answer (score 2):

The initial formula used seems correct, but $R$ should be the Rydberg constant for that *particular* nucleus.
$$R = 1.0973731\times 10^7 \left(\frac{m_{\rm nuc}}{m_{\rm nuc} + m_e}\right),$$
where $m_{\rm nuc}$ is the mass of the nucleus and $m_e$ is the mass of the electron.

Clearly the term in the bracket, although close to 1 is not exactly 1 and $R$ is actually a little bit smaller than you have assumed.

I think you have used the formula based on the Bohr model, which assumes that the nucleus is stationary and effectively has infinite mass compared with the electron. Taking account of a finite ratio of the nuclear to the electron mass causes a small shift in the energy levels.